# OpenVPN - Options error: Unrecognized option or missing or extra parameter(s) (2.4.5)

Tags: networking, vpn, openvpn

I'm having a slight issue with configuration of my OpenVPN server. Before changing the configuration (hardening) I was unable to connect to the server using Apple devices, however was fine using Windows/Android clients. Now, I am able to connect through Apple/Android devices but not the Windows client. I have checked for deprecated options, can't find any in the config. Any help is much appreciated.

Full Error:

```
Options error: Unrecognized option or missing or extra parameter(s) in home.ovpn:1: homeVPN (2.4.5)
Use --help for more information.
```

Config File (Hid sensitive info):

```
homeVPN
dev tun
proto udp
remote IP_ADDRESS PORT
float
ncp-ciphers AES-128-GCM:AES-256-GCM:AES-128-CBC:AES-256-CBC
cipher AES-128-CBC
auth SHA256
compress lzo
keepalive 15 60
auth-user-pass
remote-cert-tls server
<ca>
### CA CERT HERE
</ca>
<cert>
### CERT HERE
</cert>
<key>
### KEY HERE
</key>
<tls-crypt>
### TA KEY HERE
</tls-crypt>
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
```

Comment: You're missing to insert CA, Cert, Key and TLS certificate and key in client.ovpn file.

Comment: Hi - sorry if I didn't make it clear. Those are in the actual file - I removed it for security reasons

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It tells you very exactly what’s wrong:

```
Options error: Unrecognized option or missing or extra parameter(s) in home.ovpn:1: homeVPN (2.4.5)
```

(emphasis mine)

Line 1 contains

```
homeVPN
```

That’s obviously not an OpenVPN option, so you need to either remove it or make it a comment by making it

```
# homeVPN
```

After that, it’ll be a valid config file.

Comment: Thanks - changed it to "client" as it was on the export and it worked. Thanks for your time, and sorry for my lack of attention to detail ;D

Comment: I concur, I had to comment three lines in my configuration file but then it just worked.

Answer (score 1):

I use linux openvpn on Mint Linux Linux Mint 18.3 Sylvia \n \l .....  the config files provided by perfect had parameters that were calling out errors...

I removed the single line that had the string  "ncp-disable"    and    "compress", and all was well afterwards...

not sure what the issue is, but it now works...